# Find first occurence of a number in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with numbers in column B like this:

```
Row Number        Column B (ID)           Column C
    1                1                    Date
    2                1                    Date
    3                1                    Date
    4                2                    Date
    5                2                    Date
    6                2                    Date
```

If a user clicks, lets say Row 2, which has an ID of 1 then I want VBA code which will get the value from column C from the row which has the first occurrence of the ID number, which in this case is row 1 which has our ID number 1.

So user clicks on a cell in Row 2 which has an ID of 1 and this shows a message box with the value from Row 1 Column C.

Is this possible?

Code:

```
    'Get first occurence of tender ID

    Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Range("B:B")
Dim i6 As Integer
i6 = findValues("first", "1", rng)

If i6
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that you will likely want to do something more than just a MsgBox with the returned values but perhaps this will get you started.

```
Sub date_by_selection()
    Dim rw As Long, val As Variant

    val = Selection.Cells(1).Value
    With Sheets("Sheet3")   '<~~ set this worksheet properly!
        MsgBox Application.Index(.Columns(3), Application.Match(val, .Columns(2), 0))
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
Public Sub find()

Dim rg As Range

For Each rg In Range("a:b")
    If rg.Cells(1, 1) = "1" Then
        Call MsgBox(rg.Cells(1, 2))
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```